# Get specific div id from JSON appended data

Tags: arrays, ajax, json

I am trying to get id of an element which was appended by json returned function.

I have two codes running, 
1. First block, takes the id of select option, execute the ajax and append the returned data to a div.

```
        <select id="nutrifacts" class="form-control" name="nutrifacts">
        <option>... </option>
        </select>

        $('#nutrifacts').on('change', function() {         
        var ingmainID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
        var ingid = $('select[name=nutrifacts]').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://nutrisubset.php',
        data: { ingvalue : ingid },
        success: function(data){
        //alert(data);
        $('#nutri-subset').html(data);
        }
```

the data appended to div#nutri-subset is

```
    <select name="sub-ingredients" class="form-control" id="sub-ingredients">
    <option value="soemvalue" id="someid">sometext2</option>
    <option value="soemvalue2" id="someid2">soemvalue2</option>
    </select>
```

here I am trying to get the id of the **selected option** but have no luck,
I have searched on the site and have tried some accepted answers as well.

This is what I had tried lately.

```
    $('#nutri-subset #sub-ingredients').on('change', function() {
     alert('clicked');
    var ingmainIDx = $('#sub-ingredients').children(":selected").attr("id");
        alert(ingmainIDx);
    });
```

But still not working, not even the alert!

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at the console? If you run your code _before_ the ajax it won't find the element 'sub-ingredients' so it won't be able to associate it's change event with your callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code ,

```
$('#nutri-subset').on('change','#sub-ingredients', function() {
     alert('clicked');
    var ingmainIDx = $('#sub-ingredients').children(":selected").attr("id");
        alert(ingmainIDx);
    });
```

Dynamic id should be after the **.on('change','#sub-ingredients'**.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the problem, your code worked. Thanks man.